Распознавание голоса не распознает запросы pocketsphinx
Компилируется без ошибок. Обработка запроса происходит так:
ps_start_utt(ps);
Pa_StartStream(stream);
char character;
character = getchar();
const char* hyp;
while (true)
{
    ps_process_raw(ps, buf, newn, FALSE, FALSE);
    hyp = ps_get_hyp(ps, NULL);
    auto currentTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto elapsedTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(currentTime - startTime).count();
    if (elapsedTime >= maxDuration)
    {
        break;
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
}
auto currentTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
Pa_StopStream(stream);
ps_end_utt(ps);

Отправка запроса на сервер:
std::string url = "https://www.google.ru/search?q=";
if (hyp == NULL)
{
    MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("Запрос не распознан\n\nДополнительная информация:\nВведен пустой запрос"), TEXT("Прерывание процесса"), MB_OK);
    return;
}
else
{
    Pa_StopStream(stream);
    Pa_CloseStream(stream);
    Pa_Terminate();
    ps_free(ps);
    ps_config_free(config);
    url += hyp;
    ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", url.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}

Стоит принудительная пауза 10 сек, иначе выдает результат запрос не распознан. Доступ к микрофону запрашивает, но по истечении 10 секунд результат всегда одинаковый, это

ЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭ


